# Plot3D instant crash 11.3 GUI

Tags: front-end, crash

I was attempting

```
Plot3D[Abs[E^-Sqrt[s + 1/s] /. s -> x + I y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

on M'ma 11.3.0.0 on Linux (64-bit).  The GUI crashes instantly (window removed, process tree terminated) on attempting to evaluate that expression.  The CLI does not.

Does anyone on a different version of M'ma or this version and a different hosting OS experience difficulties evaluating that expression in the graphical front-end?

Comment: Works fine on Wolfram Cloud 12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 18, 2020) and desktop 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020).

Comment: No problem on 11.1 on Windows 8.